# Is there a way (possibly via a 3rd party plugin) to read/write PDF annotations/comments in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

Is there a way (possibly via a 3rd party plugin) to read/write PDF annotations/comments in Illustrator?

We use PDF comments heavily in our workflow with Illustrator.  The problem is to add/edit/view these comments we need to use two programs.

The comments are used to embed markup language that our custom software which converts it into a web based template.  This is why is it is so critical to be easily accesed from our primary design tool (Illustrator).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Really not sure why you'd want to. Using Acrobat the comments have so many more options to track what has and has not been addressed. I generally opent the PDF in Acrobat to view comments, and open the PDF in Illustrator edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I've found to do what you're asking for. In your situation, I would probably be thinking along the lines of shifting that embedded comment workflow to document metadata, or the entire workflow to InDesign/IDML or perhaps utilizing JDF (which is also XML).

If that's too radical a thought, and I can understand why it would be, it might be worthwhile casting about for a skilled scripter who's familiar with the AI and PDF DOMs and could whip up a custom panel that would populate with the information you need and embed it in the PDF output directly or as JDF/metadata.